# Handle javascript array in PHP, inserting multiple rows in to db

Tags: php, javascript

Let's say that I send a JS array to a php page using an http post:

```
var tags = ['foo', 'bar'];
```

My goal is to do a new INSERT in my db table for each tag (because I suppose I can't insert multiple rows with one query)? How do I loop through the array and insert the values in to the table using `mysql_query`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the post parameters in form `tags[]=foo&tags[]=bar`. PHP should receive them as a `$_REQUEST['tags']` array. Then iterate as normal in PHP.

Alternately, use `JSON.stringify(thing)` on clientside to get a string representation you can send as a single parameter, then restore it with `json_decode(param)` on PHP side - and again you get a PHP array.

You can iterate a PHP array using the `foreach ($array as $element) { ... }` construct.

Also, you can insert multiple rows with one INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2)
VALUES
  ('foo', 'bar'),
  ('baz', 'moo')
```